# Need to understand why my function is working in this way

Tags: python, function, input

I just started learning python and in some exercises about functions im doing in order to practice, i came with the following simple idea which I wanted to test in a bigger way later, here is my code:

```
def test_function(firstn):
    firstn = input("introduce your name: ") ## assigns the value of the introduced value
    print(firstn + " Perez") ##prints the function + the surname

 test_function(0) ## calls the function and executes
```

Everything works as expected, the thing is that, when I first finished the code on the last line on which I called the function "test_function" and if I left the value between the parenthesis unspecified, the code failed with the following error message:

```
def test_function(firstn):
    firstn = input("introduce your name: ")
    print(firstn + " Perez")

test_function() ## without any value

"TypeError: test_function() missing 1 required positional argument: 'firstn'"
```

My question is, why it is working when I call the function with any random number in between the parenthesis and it does not work when I just call the function without any value inside them?

Thanks for any feedback provided or any advice you might have in order to improve my use of this.

Comment: `def test_function(firstn)` defines a function taking 1 required parameter. You don't actually use the name, in fact you rebind it to a different value. Likely you just wanted to `def test_function()` to define a function with no input parameters.

Comment: See [Defining Functions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions) in the Python tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your function as one that takes a single argument:

`def test_function(firstn):`. That is why it throws an exception if you try to call it with no arguments.  Note that you don't use this argument, you just over-write it with the first line within the function:

`firstn = input("introduce your name: ")`.

So your function probably should either:

- Take no arguments `def test_function():`

  or
- Use that argument somehow

Answer (score 0):

The reason why this happens is because it has no value for `firstn` and therefore can't change `firstn` If you have a function like:

```
def test(context):
    context = 5
    print(context)
```

You will need the `context` variable because you are defining it for the first time within the `def test` and if you don't have the context variable, it will look to the computer like context is a randomly created variable within a function, and you can't define variables within functions.

Comment: You can create local variables in a function. Just assign a value. In a function `foo = "bar"` will cause python to create a local variable "foo".

Answer (score 0):

You specified the argument `firstn` in your function definition. It has to be provided in the function call, otherwise you get that exception.
Since you overwrite the `firstn` variable immediately in the first line, it is absolutely useless to have it as an argument.

Comment: So, I assume its ok if i only define my function and introduce the rest of the code within it, in order to call it at some other point on my code, right?

Comment: Yes, the point is that you should remove the argument if you don't intend to use it inside the function.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to write a function that can take 0 or 1 arguments, you can provide a "default value" for arguments like this:

```
def test_function(firstn="Mr"):
    firstn = input("introduce your name: ") ## assigns the value of the introduced value
    print(firstn + " Perez") ##prints the function + the surname

 test_function("Bob") ## calls the function and executes
 test_function() ## calls the function and executes
```

Notice the way I have declared `def test_function(firstn="Mr")` where `firstn` has a "default value" that is `"Mr"`.

Answer (score 0):

Python functions take two types of parameters: Required positional parameters and optional named parameters. For instance, in

```
def test_function(firstn, middlen=""):
    print(firstn, middlen, "Perez")
```

the caller must supply `firstn` but `middlen` is optional.

In your case, you reassign `firstn` so there was no need to have it in the first place. Simply

```
def test_function():
    firstn = input("introduce your name: ") ## assigns the value of the introduced value
    print(firstn + " Perez") ##prints the function + the surname
```

That assignment to `firstn` creates a local variable "firstn" and gives it the value returned from `input`. This variable is destroyed when the function exits.